# Codeigniter Active Records get where

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The documentation only mentions these parameters.

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);
```

Is the above absolute? or is there more details hidden somewhere in the codeigniter userguide?

I would like to know how to only return rows of a specific column.

For example, on a Person table. I only wanted the name of the row in person table with the person_id of 1. Or for example, on children table, i want to get only  the rows for child_name of parent_id = 1.

```
$this->db->get_where('person', array('person_id' => 1))->result_array();
```

Say Children table has 4 columns.

Person_id Child_id Child_Name and Child_age

So 1 person id can have as many children. Say the values are.

1 1 john 4
1 2 peter 3
1 3 michael 7
2 4 noah 10

So i only want the name of the children of person_id = 1.

Comment: "I would like to know how to only return rows of a specific column." ... you *are* doing it right? `$this->db->get_where('person', array('person_id' => 1))->result_array();`

Comment: I edited my question. What i mean of a specific column is that, in a table with 4 cols i only want the row of 1 col to return.

say for person_id = 1, i only want the column of person_name to return and not all of the columns.

Comment: ah you want to only `SELECT` the `person_name` field?

Comment: Is it possible to do it like this?

$this->db->select('name');
$query = $this->db->get_where();
??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do method chaining as such:

```
public function get() {
    return $this->db->select('person_name')
                    ->get_where('person', array('person_id' => 1))
                    ->result_array();
}
```

Or just simply

```
public function get() {
    $this->db->select('person_name');
    return $this->db->get_where('person', array('person_id' => 1))->result_array();
}
```

But the `get_where` or similar function of CI query builder don't have in-built select statements other than `$this->db->select('somename')`

Comment: I only needed to add $this->db->select('column_name');

before my get_where statement. I didn't think this through. Wasted a question on me. I'll accept your answer anyway. ^^